# How can I make this R loop more efficient?

Tags: r, performance, processing-efficiency

I have a set of real values (>50k) and, for each one, I want to see what proportion of permuted *for that site* are greater than the value observed. I've solved this problem using the following for-loop, but it seems to run slowly and I was wondering if anybody had suggestions to optimize it or a more efficient method.

Thanks in advance!

In this code, real[,3] corresponds to the vector of real values, matrix is the results output, and perm[,3] contains all permuted values.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(real)) {
  real[i,3] -> output[i,1]
  subset(perm, perm[,1] == row.names(real[i,])) -> sims
  nrow(sims[sims[,3] > significance[i,1],] ) -> output[i,3]
  nrow(sims) -> output[i,2]
}
```

Head of the real file: only the 3rd column is important for this

```
chr10_1012663  134.1894  130.9915 -3.197876e+00 -2.411963e-02        0
chr10_1012716  144.3250  130.9433 -1.338170e+01 -9.730331e-02        0
chr10_10160551 155.6744  138.7002 -1.697420e+01 -1.154519e-01        0
chr10_10163175 304.4715  261.5272 -4.294435e+01 -1.520394e-01        0
chr10_1018272  133.0447  133.0447 -8.930860e-08 -6.712676e-10        0
```

Head of the perm file: only 3rd column is important as well. This file contains 50 permutations per each site in the real file.

```
chr10_1012663  99.94432 130.9915  3.104717e+01  2.705191e-01  1
chr10_1012716 130.94332 130.9433 -3.600817e-08 -2.749906e-10  0
chr10_10160551 138.63097 138.7002  6.921823e-02  4.991739e-04  1
chr10_10163175 261.52720 261.5272  4.579061e-08  1.750893e-10  1
```

Head of the output file: columns are (i) the real value, (ii) the number of permuations scored, and (iii) the number of permutations greater than the real value.

```
-3.197876e+00   50   39 
-9.730331e-02   50   44 
-1.154519e-01   50   48 
-1.520394e-01   50   49  
-6.712676e-10   50   38
```

Comment: Can you post some minimally useful / reproducible sample data and expected output? Then, we can help you with working code.

Comment: can you give us a (small) [reproducible example](http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000) please?

Comment: Can you provide the output of `dput(head(real))`, `dput(head(perm))`, and `dput(head(matrix))`? Also, it is typically not a good idea to name your objects after functions. Matrix is a function in R, so you should name that object something else

Comment: Thanks for the comments; I've added some examples although to provide anything completely reproducible would be several hundred lines.    I've also changed matrix to output; my actual data has different matrix names, but I thought I would simplify them here.

Comment: You can try library(compiler);enableJIT(3)  - sometimes it increaseas performance in several times

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The main post changed, so I edited some stuff to match.

If you're looping over all rows of `real`, then you might as well assign the vector `real[,3]` to `output[,1]` in one go:

```
output[,1] <- real[,3]
```

Since you always have 50 permutations, you can simply assign 50 to `output[,2]`:

```
output[,2] <- 50
```

Next, you are trying to find the row name in `real` that matches the value of the first column in `perm` and store the corresponding row from `perm` in `sims`. I'd recommend not to store information in row names, but even if you do, there's a better way to do this (see below). Since you then only use `sims[,3]`, you might as well only subset the 3rd column from `perm`.

```
sims <- sapply(row.names(real), function(x) perm[perm[,1] == x, 3])
for (i in 1:nrow(real)) output[i,3] <- length(sims[[i]][sims[[i]] > significance[i,1]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The second step still takes a while, but it is much faster than before!

Comment: Which step exactly? I'll see if I can think of something faster. Edit: nevermind, I can't count. Anyway, I think it can be done faster... Are there always 50 permutations for every location?

Comment: Yes, there will always be the same number of permutations for each site

Comment: Well, I can't figure it out. I think `sapply` is your best option without complicating things too much. Also, you can save some extra time by just saying `output[,2] <- 50`.

Comment: Yes, that will save a bit. Thank you very much for your help!